# Exceptions won't bubble up

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, windows-mobile

I'm working on a Windows Mobile application. I've got a main menu form with buttons on it and all other forms are launched from here. Each bit of code that launches a child form is wrapped in a try/catch block. If an exception is thrown then it is logged and a message displayed. This is the only place where I handle errors. In some places further down the stack in the business or data layers I may have a try/catch block but I simply add some details to the exception and throw a new one with the original as the inner exception.

Now this all seems to work OK most of the time. The problem is that sometimes exceptions are thrown further down in the business or data layer and they don't bubble up to my exception handling code at the top. I've got no idea why this happens. I'm not doing any multi-threading or anything else tricky.

Update:

Thanks very much for all the suggestions! I haven't been able to pick a solution though. This problem has been going on for a while. I'll come back and update this if I ever figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Brandon. Visual Studio stops at the low-level exception in the data layer with the message "Unhandled Exception".

This is normal. There is a setting in visual studio under "Tools -> Options -> Debugging" called "Enable the [Exception assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t16fe6f4.aspx)" which will break on exceptions.

It's to make it easier to debug applications. Just hit F5 to let your application continue and you'll see that it will continue to bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already covered this possibility, but just to be thorough: You are sure that you don't have anything like the following anywhere...

```
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        try{
            ...
            ...
        }
        catch {}
    }
```

Obviously that would just ignore the error rather than pass it up the stack.

Assuming the above is not the case, then can you provide more detail about what happens when an exception occurs?  Do you know there is an exception because a box pops up telling you about it and are you able to see where the exception occurred in your code, or do you just see that your code is not behaving properly and assume an exception occurred?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brandon. No I don't have any empty catch statements. It makes me mad when I see other devs writing code like that! What happens is that the exception is displayed in the generic windows error screen and my top-level exception handling code (in the UI layer) is never called. If I'm debugging then Visual Studio just stops at the point where the low-level exception is thrown (in the data layer). It's really odd.

Comment: Let me ask you a couple more questions:
What do you mean by Visual Studio just stops?  Does it 'break' where the exception is so you can view it or does it literally stop so the program is not executing anymore?

And what if you're not debugging?  Does it crash your application then or just continue on?

Comment: Also, I will assume that in addition to not having any 'empty' catch statements, that your catch statements all rethrow an exception as well.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Visual Studio stops at the low-level exception in the data layer with the message "Unhandled Exception". My code here is accessing the database and I have a try/catch block and the catch statement is something like 'Throw new exception("Db Error", ex);' so as you can see I rethrow the exception as an inner exception.

Comment: If it's possible, the first thing I'd try would be to comment out the try/catch lines and cause the error.  This will at least help isolate the problem a little more.

The only thing that comes to my mind right now is that possibly the Exception (or InnerException) is a of a type that is referenced in the data layer dll, but not in the dll or exe it needs to be passed up to.  I've honestly never thought about that before and I'm not sure how that gets handled.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I'll just leave this in the "completely mental" category for now. I'm only catching and throwing standard .Net exceptions. I'm not using any custom exception classes in that part of the code. I've even found this problem occurs if I simply add a line in the datalayer like "Throw new Exception("meh");". It's really odd :(

Comment: I would be interested to know what the problem was if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to notify the user and log the exception you can try adding an [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)

However please note (from the MSDN documentation):  *This event allows your Windows Forms application to handle otherwise unhandled exceptions that occur in Windows Forms threads. Attach your event handlers to the ThreadException event to deal with these exceptions, which will leave your application in an unknown state. Where possible, exceptions should be handled by a structured exception handling block.*

```
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);


    void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle
    }
```

You can also add an event handler to the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.  It is important to note that you will not be able to recover from here.  However, you will at a minimum be able to log the exception for further debugging and notify the user.  Caution should be used (again from the MSDN documentation):

*This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application. If sufficient information about the state of the application is available, other actions may be undertaken — such as saving program data for later recovery. Caution is advised, because program data can become corrupted when exceptions are not handled.*

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify the user and log the exception
    }
```

Comment: @jgauffin This would help because he is attempting to 1)  Log the exception, and 2)  Show a message to the user.  At a minimum the logging can be accomplished inside of these handlers.

Comment: No, he is trying to get his exceptions to travel up the call stack properly.

Comment: You are correct, however my answer was an attempt to address what I thought was the intention of the code.  I should prefaced my answer with that.  The question states:  "Each bit of code that launches a child form is wrapped in a try/catch block. If an exception is thrown then it is logged and a message displayed".  If this is the true intention of the code then my answer will achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Well. Then you should not have included the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` since it do not handle the exception. The application will crash no matter if the event is invoked or not.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree.  If the intention is to notify the user of an error either through a log or a message, then the AppDomain UnhandledException event can be used to achieve that.  Depending on the application, it's often better to have some indication to the user that something has gone wrong.

Comment: His exception handling is already correct and he do notify the user. (read his post). There is a chance that you didn't understand my comment: The application can ***never*** recover (as in continue) no matter how or what you do in the callback for `UnhandledException`. And far from all applications should stop working because of an unhandled exception. Hence it's a bad advice for everyone that just want to catch the exception, notify the user and then let the application to continue running.

Comment: I did understand your comment but depending on what Mark is attempting to achieve it doesn't matter.  If he wants to continue running then you are correct - handling the AppDomain event would not work.  However, as you state, nothing will help in that situation.  So, my preference is to at least track that event for debugging and logging. If that is Mark's intention - to notify the user that something has gone wrong then this answer is valid.

Comment: He says: `I'm not doing any multi-threading`. Hence,  `UnhandledException` will never be triggered if `ThreadException` is being handled. But since he do write that he has catches in the proper places, he do not need an additional layer of catches

Comment: But your right about one thing: `they don't bubble up to my exception handling code` can really mean anything. I'll remove my down vote if you edit your answer to elaborate.

Comment: @jgauffin is correct, this answer needed some clarification to be useful.  I have updated to add additional information and caveats to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just got burned by this. Finally I spotted the problem:

```
main()
{
   blah x = new blah(); //after a while I finally figured out this needs to
                        //be inside the try block with "//work"
   try
   {
      //work
   }
   catch
   {
      //I expected it to be handled here
   }
{

class blah
{
   blah()  //constructor
   {
       throw; //debugger tells me this is unhandled
   } 
 }
```